# add and remove class in query after click

Tags: jquery

i am writing jQuery function for my website. when user click any of the element it will add a css class and after if they click another element it will remove the class.
here is my code:

```
<body>
<dl>
    <dt>What's you name</dt>
        <dd>My name is name</dd>
    <dt>What is your occupation</dt>
        <dd>I am a web developer</dd>
    <dt>What do you like</dt>
        <dd>I like programming</dd>
</dl>
<script src="../jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("dd").hide();
        $("dl").on("click", "dt", function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass("back")
                    .next()
                    .slideDown()
                    .siblings("dd")
                    .slideUp()
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: use `removeClass` to remove a class

Comment: i want to add class "back" when user click any dt element and remove the class when they click another dt element.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
$("dl").on("click", "dt", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings("dt").removeClass("back");
        $this.addClass("back")
                .next()
                .slideDown()
                .siblings("dd")
                .slideUp();         
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NSTF5/)

Comment: What significance does `$this` have vs `$(this)` in this context?

Comment: @RPM It's just caching the selector in a variable so that it doesn't have to be retrieved by jQuery multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("dd").hide();
    $("dl").on("click", "dt", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings('dt.back').removeClass('back');
        $this.addClass("back")
            .next()
            .slideToggle()
            .siblings("dd")
            .slideUp()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q63rU/)